# PHP Or Javascript Customized Label on packaging

Tags: javascript, php

I have a client that wants to have a customized label on their product where their customer can type the text on the label that they want. However I honestly have no clue about how to do this. I've looked at the PHP function 'imagettftext' but not sure if this would be decent as it doesn't seem as if you can style the text very much. The best example are the customized card websites that are about. Where they have the fancy text that you can edit in real time.

I'm unsure about how to do this, I've found away to do it with javascript an edited the code a bit.

```
<div>
    <label>Insert your name<input id='name' type='text'></label><br>
    <label>X<input id='x' type='text' value="0"></label><br>
    <label>Y<input id='y' type='text' value="0"></label><br>
    <label>Choose your picture<input id="f" type="file"></label>
    <img id='custom' style='position: absolute; left: -9999px'>
    <img id='template' style='position: absolute; left: -9999px' src='https://picsum.photos/250'>
</div>
<canvas></canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
    customImage = document.querySelector('img#custom'),
    backgroundImage = document.querySelector('img#template'),
    nameInput = document.querySelector('input#name'),
    xInput = document.querySelector('input#x'),
    yInput = document.querySelector('input#y'),
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    backgroundLoaded = false,
    customImageLoaded = false;

nameInput.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
   redraw(); 
});
yInput.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
   redraw(); 
});
xInput.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
   redraw(); 
});
document.querySelector('img#template').addEventListener('load', function () {
    canvas.width = this.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = this.clientHeight;
    backgroundLoaded = true;
    
    redraw();
});

document.querySelector('#f').addEventListener('change', function(ev) {
    var f = ev.target.files[0];
    var fr = new FileReader();

    fr.onload = function(ev2) {
        console.dir(ev2);

        customImage.src = ev2.target.result;
        customImage.addEventListener('load', function () {
            customImageLoaded = true;
            redraw();
        });
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(f);
    
});

// redraw, using templates

function redraw() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawBackground();
    drawCustomImage();
    drawName();
}

// draw functions

function drawBackground () {
    if (backgroundLoaded) {
        context.drawImage(document.querySelector('img#template'), 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
}

function drawCustomImage () {
    if (customImageLoaded) {
        context.drawImage(customImage, 50, 50, 100, 100);
    }
}

function drawName () {
    context.fillStyle = 'white';
    context.font = '48px serif';
    context.fillText(nameInput.value, xInput.value, canvas.height - yInput.value);
}

</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nkgxhb7t/2/

However I'm unsure if there is a better way of doing this. Would love any advice you could give me :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you clarify the specific question?  At first it sounds like you're running into a problem, but then just before the code sample it sounds like you're indicating that your code currently works.  Is there a problem you're trying to solve?  If you're just asking for feedback about your code then you may be looking for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @David I'm asking for advice really, the best direction to take this. As the code I've posted works... But its very basic for what I'm trying to do and I'm wondering if there is any a library or anything that could help or just generally a better method all together.

Comment: What you're asking is a bit off-topic here then, I'm afraid.  If the code works and you'd like general feedback on it, please see the aforementioned Code Review community.  Recommendations for 3rd party libraries are off-topic here as well, I'm not sure if there's a community for that but you can certainly look for one on the [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) site.  For more information about this community and how we can help you, you are encouraged to start with the [tour] and read [ask].